# Using built-in WPF Settings for non ClickOnce application

Tags: wpf, settings, clickonce

I have a WPF application that will deployed using InnoSetup (and so presumably will not be a ClickOnce application) that stores user settings with the built-in settings under Properties in the Visual Studio project. I need that the user settings are preserved after each update.

However I have found that if the assembly version changes then the app overwrites the user settings.

In this article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228995.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it explains for non-clickOnce applications the user settings are stored in the 'Documents and Settings' folder (which is OK), however this is not the case for my project - Is there a setting somewhere in the project so I can declare it a 'non-ClickOnce' application and so therefore get the settings to appear somewhere accessible?

Secondly, I would like that the settings are updated according to that article linked above, will this happen for non-ClickOnce applications?

Comment: The files are always accessible if you know where they're stored: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0 (on Windows 7 & 8).

Comment: Yes but the actual location under that directory changes according to the assembly version, the app then seems to consider this a brand new install and ignores the existing settings.

Comment: What do you mean by *the app then seems to consider this a brand new install and ignores the existing settings*? Mine doesn't... how does yours? Are you trying to manually access the files?

Comment: In the directory that contains the `user.config` files (which in my case is actually `C:\Users\Alien\AppData\Local\Rada\MicroBugless.vshost.exe_Url_lqstcui2lpkqbhcxys2vrxu4ekot2oj2`, the `Apps\2.0` only contains files for the 'Windows Phone Power Tools'), there is a directory for each build/assembly version of my app (the app is configured to increment the assembly version for each build of the app) - in each is a `user.config`. This directory is known because I looked for it - it will likely be in another directory when deployed to another machine.